# jQuery basic plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I would like to check in my plugin for a specific class,

```
    $.fn.Required = function(){

    return this.each(function(){

    if($(this).hasClass("required")){
    $(this).after("*required");
    alert("test");

    }
    });
```

Like you can see I try to put the word "*required" after the object this when it has the class "required"

If you have any solution, your free to post!
- thnx for reading -

Comment: Your `html` will help more to us.

Comment: You were right, I thought that I made the right class but I didnt!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$.fn.Required = function(){ 
    return this.each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("required")){
            $(this).after("<label>*required</label>");
            alert("test");
        }
    });
};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acaJN/)